# Valid Tensor equation

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

Let us have the equation as;

$A_{{\mu}{\nu}}$$B_{\mu}$=$C_{{\mu}{\nu}}$ , $\mu$ and $\nu$ are free indices.

Is the above equation a valid tensor equation? If not then what correction should be made to make the above equation a valid tensor equation?

Comment: What [would be valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is $A_{\mu\nu}B^\mu=C_\nu$.

Answer (score 4):

Tensors are characterized by the property that they transform in a predictable way under a change of coordinates, e.g.
$$A_{\mu \nu} \longrightarrow \widetilde{A}_{\alpha \beta} = \sum_{\mu \nu}  R_{\alpha \mu} A_{\mu \nu} R_{\nu \beta},$$
where $R_{\mu_\nu}$ is a transformation matrix which I've here assumed to be orthogonal ($R_{\mu \nu} = (R^{-1})_{\nu\mu}$). When you ask whether your equation is a *valid tensor equation*, you probably mean whether both the left- and right-hand-side represent a tensor. To test this, apply a coordinate transformation to both sides of the equation and see if it still holds in the new coordinate system. In your case, it will *not*, because on the left-hand side the transformation matrix will appear 3 times (once for every free index), and on the right-hand side it will only appear twice.

A general rule to form invariant tensor equations is to follow the Einstein summation convention: repeated indices are always summed over, and free indices all have different symbols. Thus you could write
$$A_{\alpha \beta} B_\gamma = C_{\alpha \beta \gamma}$$
or
$$A_{\alpha \beta} B_\beta \equiv \sum_\beta A_{\alpha \beta} B_\beta = C_\alpha.$$

Of course these equations are different to your original equation, so when you ask what correction should be made, there is no unique answer - it depends on what you want!

Note also that despite not being an (invariant) tensor equation, your equation may still be valid in a particular coordinate system. Such non-invariant equations can for instance arise when changing explicitly from one basis to another. However, if your equation is supposed to represent a law of physics, it has to be invariant, as the <s>[equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle)</s> [principle of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity) tells us.

Comment: Thanks, edited!